# Apparmor DENIED ACCESS to soft links

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, symbolic-link, app-armor

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) but this issues has been happening since I am using an old Ubuntu (19.04 & 19.10). So I have 2 hard disk drives - one is an SSD (small size), the other a SATA (big size). The reason I attached a big SATA disk is that I have to host a large MySQL database.

So the SATA hard is mounted at `/mnt/sata/` and I created the following symlinks:

```
/var/lib/mysql -> /mnt/sata/mysql
```

I am doing this because I don't want to change the default configuration for MySQL and AppArmor. But when I try to start the `mysql` service, I am getting the following error from `apparmor`.

```
Apr 29 20:45:26 home kernel: [17678.024673] audit: type=1400 audit(1588189526.914:156): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/mnt/sata/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test" pid=58497 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=125 ouid=125
```

So it means `apparmor` prevents MySQL from accessing the data directory which is `/var/lib/mysql` and then symlinked to `/mnt/sata/mysql`. If I add the following rules to the `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`, the issue is gone.

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld {
    ...


    # Allow data dir access (existing)
    /var/lib/mysql/ r,
    /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,

    # Allow symlinks as well (added for symlink)
    /mnt/sata/mysql r,
    /mnt/sata/mysql rwk,
    ...
}
```

As you can see, the `apparmor` profile for MySQL already allows for access to `/var/lib/mysql` which is, in my case, then symlinked to `/mnt/sata/mysql`. So it looks like `apparmor` followed the symlink and tried to look for rules for the symlink's target.

Any solution that allows me to start the mysql server without having to add the access rules for the symlinks to the `apparmor` profile?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a bind-mount instead of a soft link:

```
mount -bind /mnt/sata/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

You can also put this in `/etc/fstab`

```
/mnt/sata/mysql /var/lib/mysql none bind
```